# Xterm cannot display more than 11 window

Tags: x11, xterm

In a script I have a loop on N tests that runs a command in an xterm window for each test. 
N may be 30.
With N =16 I have noticed that I have only 11 xterm windows for the first 11 tests were created.

For test 12 I got this error in my log file:
"Xterm Xt error: Can't open display:..."

1- Is there any limitation on the number of xterm windows that can be opened simultaneously?

2- in my script how can I manage to check if the xterm window was opened without error (is there any way to do it without parsing my log file? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of windows depends on your X server (not on the xterm program — or other clients, generally).  Eleven windows sounds low (perhaps your machine has little memory).

To check for failure, your script should look at the exit-status (usually `$?`) when `xterm` exits.  There are several possible codes, documented in the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-ERROR-MESSAGES).